# dapper: Get result and count at same time using QueryMultiple

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I wrote two segments of SQL command and want to process in one query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books

SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY bookID OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

How can I use `conn.QueryMultiple` method to get `count` AND `list of books` at same time ?

btw: I don't want to create any extra entity classes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From github [example](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/Tests.QueryMultiple.cs):

```
var sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
            SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY bookID OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY";

using(var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
{
    var count = multi.Read<int>().Single();
    var results = multi.Read<YourObject>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: do you mean, I must define my own `Book` class to separate the result ? Is there a generic way to do this ? e.g: var books = multi.Read(IList)();

Comment: @ineztia, I think, you can get result as list of objects or dynamic

Comment: For extra credit, the `multi` should be in a `using` block as it is `IDisposable`.

Comment: @ineztia indeed, the *easiest* way to read a series `Book` records is to define a class `Book` that has all the fields (matching name and type) that you want to populate. However, if that is too much like hard work (hint: it shouldn't be), the non-generic `Read` API returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and you can just access `.ColumnName` etc. I strongly recommend the generic approach in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

For the better performance

```
var sql=@"SELECT *,count(*) over() as AllCount
FROM Books ORDER BY BookId OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY"

var result = result = dbConnection.Query<Book, int, Tuple<Book, int>>(sql, Tuple.Create, splitOn:"AllCount").ToList();
var count = result.Select(c => c.Item2).FirstOrDefault();
List<Book> list = result.Select(c => c.Item1).ToList();
```